# -metadata.xml Salesforce Metadata Retrieve and Deploy

Tags: metadata, xml, workbench

we have a problem with to deploy a package, the problem is the next

1. We was retrieve the metadata from Workbrench Tools with to package.xml (Example: Profile)
   in this part we saw that file name of this metadata doesn't have '**-meta.xml**' on name.
2. After we retrieved to using sfdx cli with visual studio code, but in this part the name the same file has '**-meta.xml**'
3. for this two reason, when we need to deploy package, the system return a error.

Anyone know for what is it happening to occurer this?
thanks for help us!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In (1), your package source is in **Metadata API format**. In (2), your metadata is in **SFDX (source) format**. The two formats can be converted losslessly using the [`sfdx force:source:convert`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_source.htm#cli_reference_force_source_convert) and [`sfdx force:mdapi:convert`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_mdapi.htm#cli_reference_force_mdapi_convert) commands.

Typically any source you retrieve with commands like `force:source:pull` will be in SFDX format, while retrieves using tools like Workbench will be in MDAPI format.

In some contexts, such as deploying using a Metadata API client like Workbench, you would need to convert SFDX-format source into MDAPI format.